# Can I still travel to the United States with a valid B1/B2 visa on my Syrian passport?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, syrian-citizens

I am a Syrian citizen. I want to visit my brother in the United States. Can I  travel there with an existing, valid B1/B2 visa in my Syrian passport, after latest travel ban Presidential Proclamation of December 4, 2017?

Comment: I believe the answer is yes, but the policy has changed so many times I'm really not sure.  I well post an answer when I have time to check, if nobody else has done so by then, but that probably won't be for a couple of days.

Comment: Maybe it does not apply to you, but it is important to remember for everybody who is currently living outside Syria under refugee status, that using their password *for anything* may lead to losing the refugee status and to face deportation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

The proclamation does not revoke any visas that were issued before the effective date of the proclamation, and the restrictions in the proclamation do not apply to any foreigners who had a valid visa on the effective date of the proclamation for that person. (And if you got your visa after the effective date, that would mean you must have gotten a waiver, so the proclamation also does not restrict you.) So if you have a valid visa, you should be able to travel to the US.

Comment: Do you have any sources?

Comment: @RoboKaren: the scope in section 3(a) of Executive Order 13780 limits it to people who were outside the US and who didn't have a valid visa on the effective date of the order